# How to handle popup window in Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape from a website and while scraping a popup window comes up and I am unable to close it.

I tried to isolate the X button but it shows up, element not clickable.

Is there any dynamic way I can check for the popup and close it as soon as it comes up?

Here's the [link to the site](https://www.sleepx.com/ortho-memory-foam-mattress).

This is how the popup comes up:

[image: popup screenshot]

and this is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import time
import re
import logging
import traceback
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import exc
import mysql.connector as mysql
import io
import re

options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1366,768")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en_GB'})
#options.headless = True

url='https://www.sleepx.com/ortho-memory-foam-mattress'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div').click() # popup close button by XPath
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use explicit waits provided by Selenium WebDriverWait to wait for the element visibility or clickability and then click it.
Like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import time
import re
import logging
import traceback
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import exc
import mysql.connector as mysql
import io
import re

options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1366,768")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en_GB'})
#options.headless = True

url='https://www.sleepx.com/ortho-memory-foam-mattress'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.WigzoCloseButton"))).click()
```

Comment: I forgot to specify, I manually waited quite a lot, but it still isn't clickable. another thing is you can't isolate it like this , it will always throw error I don't know why. Only XPath works. I tried running your code and it timed out

Comment: Did you try that manually or running the code? On regular or incognito mode?

Comment: In my case I let the chromedriver load for a bit before running the code for the click and yours I ran as it is.

Comment: But the pop-up appears? If does - is it inside the visible part of the screen? BTW, why do you use `("--window-size=1366,768")`? I use `"--window-size=1920,1080"` similarly to my actual screen size.

Comment: that's the problem, I tried ```element.is_displayed()``` but it returns false even after the popup has appeared. IDK what's the problem. As for the res, it's just boiler plate code. I copy it from my other scrapers

Comment: Specifically I am focusing on the X button element that's nested inside the WizgoPopupContent div which selenium cant seem to find, idk why

Comment: Are you sure you using exactly the locator I wrote in the answer? Also, try this XPath: `//div[contains(@class,'WigzoCloseButton')]`

Comment: Yes I copied it exactly, this xpath also didn't work, already tried it before

Comment: Strange... Can you try `presence_of_element_located()` instead of `visibility_of_element_located` just to see if this will catch the element or fail on timeout too?

Comment: If so I guess you have some general problem with your driver. I guess you can not see any other element as well...

Comment: can you try running the code on your end? does it work?

Comment: I don't have Python with selenium installed on my computer, only Java. Will try doing that tomorrow or on Friday, but can't promise.